# Client side html markdown conversion

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

I've been trying to create a client side editor which allows the end user to create content in html or markdown. The user has two tabs for switching between the two. I managed to find some javascript that converts markdown to html, so if a user has been writing markdown and switches to the html tab, the html equivilant is shown. I haven't been able to find a javascript that converts html to markdown, only a python script.

The python script is obviously server side. The tabs are just hyperlinks with script in there. Is there any way I can convert the markdown html when the user clicks the tab?

Comment: Are you sure you want people to edit the html directly?  At best the transition will be lossy.  There are a lot of things that can't be represented well in markdown.  For instance if I add `<span class='blue'>...</span>`, what would you want to see in the markdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to send the data to the server using AJAX, perform the conversion on the server and then return the results back to the browser. In jQuery this is as simple as e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: <converter url>,
    data: <html>
    success: function(markdown_text){
        $('#id_container').text(markdown_text);
    }
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
             alert('Error!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14):

The currently accepted answer actually tells you to do it on the *server-side*.

To really do *client-side* conversion, you could try one of these libraries (in order of popularity, measured by GitHub stars):

- [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked)
- [showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown)
- [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it)
- [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js)
- [reMarked.js](https://github.com/leeoniya/reMarked.js)

Answer (score 6):

feel free to try my lib, `reMarked.js`, for client-side html/DOM > markdown

https://github.com/leeoniya/reMarked.js

the other way around you can try `marked`, but be aware that it doesn't support some php-markdown-extra features, like parsing pretty tables http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#table

https://github.com/chjj/marked/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [WMD-Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/examples/splitscreen)? It has the ability to preview the html.